# Promise with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I've taken a look at a few questions on recursion in promises and am confused on how to implement them properly:

- [Recursive Promise in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020722/recursive-promise-in-javascript)
- [AngularJS, promise with recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607313/angularjs-promise-with-recursive-function)
- [Chaining Promises recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291003/chaining-promises-recursively)
- [Javascript Recursive Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362071/javascript-recursive-promise)

I put together a simple example (see below) - this is just an example so I can understand how to make recursion with promises work and not a representation of the code in which I'm working.

Net-net, I'd like the promise to resolve, but according to the output on node, it doesn't resolve.  Any insight into how to make this resolve?

```
var i = 0;

var countToTen = function() { 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i++;
            console.log("i is now: " + i);
            return countToTen();
        }
        else {
            resolve(i);
        }
    });
}

countToTen().then(console.log("i ended up at: " + i));
```

And the output on the console:

```
> countToTen().then(console.log("i ended up at: " + i));
i is now: 1
i is now: 2
i is now: 3
i is now: 4
i is now: 5
i is now: 6
i is now: 7
i is now: 8
i is now: 9
i is now: 10
i ended up at: 10
Promise { <pending> }
```

The promise never resolves.

Comment: change `return countToTen();` to `resolve(countToTen());` - the console will still say "pending", however, if you instead say `var p = countToten......` then you'll see p is resolved

Comment: the other issue you have is that your `.then` is wrong ... .then expects a **function** as an argument, you have supplied `undefined` (the result of running `console.log` as an argument - which is why the output to the console looked OK to you

Comment: Thank you @Jaromanda X, upvoted since you didn't write an answer, otherwise would have accepted yours.  Appreciate the response.

Comment: Yeah, don't know why I comment when I should answer :p

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look at your code as long as `i` is less than 10 you are recursing **and never resolving the promise**. You eventually resolve a promise. but it is not the promise the initial caller gets.

You need to resolve with the promise returned by the recursion. How the system works if you resolve with a promise it will still not resolve until also the value is resolved:

```js
let i = 0;
const countToTen = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (i < 10) {
      i++;
      console.log("i is now: " + i);
      resolve(countToTen());
    } else {
      resolve(i);
    }
  });

countToTen().then(() => console.log("i ended up at: " + i));
```

There was an error in the last part as well. You didn't provide a function to `then` so if you would have done something that actually would have waited you would have got the `"i ended up at: 0"` first.

Comment: you may want to also point out the incorrect usage of .then - since you changed that code too in your answer :p - because if .then was used correctly, OP would not have seen that final output

Comment: Thanks  alot it really hepled me ! i was going to ask a new question .... Just in time found this answer :-) really happy .....

Answer (score 2):

it would be better if you made `i` a parameter of the function instead of relying upon external state

```js
const countToTen = (i = 0) =>
  new Promise ((resolve, _) =>
    i < 10
      ? (console.log (i), resolve (countToTen (i + 1)))
      : resolve (i))
      
      
countToTen () .then (console.log, console.error)
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

And even better if you made `10` a parameter too

```js
const countTo = (to, from = 0) =>
  new Promise ((resolve, _) =>
    from < to
      ? (console.log (from), resolve (countTo (to, from + 1)))
      : resolve (from))

countTo (7, 2) .then (console.log, console.error)
// 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

A more generic approach is a *reverse* fold - or `unfold`

```js
const unfold = (f, init) =>
  f ( (x, acc) => [ x, ...unfold (f, acc) ]
    , () => []
    , init
    )

const countTo = (to, from = 0) =>
  unfold
    ( (next, done, acc) =>
        acc <= to
          ? next (acc, acc + 1)
          : done ()
    , from
    )

console.log (countTo (10))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9, 10 ]

console.log (countTo (7, 2))
// [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

But you want a *asynchronous* unfold, `asyncUnfold`. Now the user-supplied function `f` can be async and we get a Promise of all collected values

```js
const asyncUnfold = async (f, init) =>
  f ( async (x, acc) => [ x, ...await asyncUnfold (f, acc) ]
    , async () => []
    , init
    )

const delay = (x, ms = 50) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

const countTo = (to, from = 0) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, acc) =>
        acc <= to
          ? next (await delay (acc), await delay (acc + 1))
          : done ()
    , from
    )

countTo (10) .then (console.log, console.error)
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

countTo (7, 2) .then (console.log, console.error)
// [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

Here's a more practical example where we have a database of records and we wish to perform a recursive look-up, or something...

- `db.getChildren` accepts a node `id` and returns only the node's *immediate* children
- `traverse` accepts a node `id` and it recursively fetches all descendant children (in depth-first order)

```
const data =
  { 0 : [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  , 1 : [ 11, 12, 13 ]
  , 2 : [ 21, 22, 23 ]
  , 3 : [ 31, 32, 33 ]
  , 11 : [ 111, 112, 113 ]
  , 33 : [ 333 ]
  , 333 : [ 3333 ]
  }

const db =
  { getChildren : (id) =>
      delay (data [id] || [])
  }

const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const traverse = (id) =>
  asyncUnfold
    ( async (next, done, [ id = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
        id === Empty
          ? done ()
          : next (id, [ ...await db.getChildren (id), ...rest ])
    , [ id ]
    )

traverse (0) .then (console.log, console.error)
// [ 0, 1, 11, 111, 112, 113, 12, 13, 2, 21, 22, 23, 3, 31, 32, 33, 333, 3333 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use shared mutable state in your functions (especially when they are asynchronous). You are using `window.i` but anything can change that value, this is not needed because the `i` value is only used in your function as a counter:

```js
const later = (milliseconds,value) =>
  new Promise(
    resolve=>
      setTimeout(
        ()=>resolve(value),
        milliseconds
      )
  );

const countTo = toWhat => {
  const recur = counter =>
    later(1000,counter)
    .then(
      i=>{
        console.log(`i is now: ${i}`);
        return (i<toWhat)
          ? recur(i+1)
          : i;
      }
    )
  return recur(1);
}

countTo(10)
.then(
  i=>console.log(`i ended up at: ${i}`)
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was just an example.  "I put together a simple example (see below) - this is just an example so I can understand how to make recursion with promises work and not a representation of the code in which I'm working."

Answer (score 0):

Many members already mentioned, need to resolve with the promise returned by the recursion.

I would like to share code into `async/await` syntax.

```
const printNumber = (i) => console.log("i is now: " + i);

// recursive function to call number increment order
const recursiveCallNumber = async (i, checkCondition) => {
    // if false return it, other wise continue to next step
    if (!checkCondition(i)) return;
    // then print
    printNumber(i); 
     // then call again for print next number
    recursiveCallNumber(++i, checkCondition);
}

await recursiveCallNumber(1, (i) => i <= 10);
```